# Filtering a dataframe by list of character vectors

Tags: r, list, filter

I'm trying to filter a dataframe based on a list of character vectors and to obtain an output for each of those vectors. Here is an example to clarify my problem:

This is the type of data I have

```
fruit <- c("Apple", "Banana", "Cherry")
vegetable <- c("Leek", "Courgette")
ls <- list(fruit, vegetable)
df <- data.frame(type = c("Apple", "Courgette", "Cherry"), 
                 quantity = c(10, 5, 3))
```

and I would like to filter my dataframe `df` using the list `ls` to obtain a list or new dataframes filtered. The format of the output does not really matter, the information I ultimately need is to find out the proportions of each list element that are findable in `df`. In numbers, that would be:
there is only 66.67% of the values of `fruit` in the dataframe `df` (Apple and Cherry) and 50% of the values of `vegetable` in the dataframe (Courgette) `df`. In dataset/list format, it could for instance take the form:

```
> new_df_fruit
    type
1  Apple
2 Cherry

> new_df_vegetable
       type
1 Courgette
```

Taking inspiration from this question: [R: "Filter" columns in a data frame by a list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41863722/r-filter-columns-in-a-data-frame-by-a-list), I tried to run the code

```
newDF <- df[which((names(df) %in% fruit ==TRUE)),]
```

But this didn't work and I'm not sure how I would use the whole list as input and receive another list or a bunch of new datasets as output.
Thanks!

Comment: how do you get 66% and 50%

Comment: For the fruit vector it was 66% because 2 out of the 3 values present in the vector were also present in the df. The 50% was because 1 out of the 2 values was also in df.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
#Code
L <- lapply(ls,function(x) data.frame(type=x[x %in% df$type]))
names(L) <- paste0('new_df_',c('fruit','vegetable'))
```

Output:

```
L
$new_df_fruit
    type
1  Apple
2 Cherry

$new_df_vegetable
       type
1 Courgette
```

Answer (score 1):

We can use loop over the `ls`, `subset` the 'df', use `list2env` to create new objects

```
list2env(setNames(lapply(ls, function(x) subset(df, 
     type %in% x, select = type)),
         paste0('new_df_', c('fruit', 'vegetable'))), .GlobalEnv)
```

-output

```
new_df_fruit
#    type
#1  Apple
#3 Cherry

new_df_vegetable
#       type
#2 Courgette
```